# how to forward outlook server to use thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap, pop3

my university created an outlook email for me **username@university.com** i can't see if the email uses pop3 or imap, i have only access to the mailbox, i sign it to it from hotmail.com, i don't want to check my email, i prefer to:

1) use thunderbird to check the email (i'm a linux guy, i don't have outlook software)

2)forward emails from the university email to my gmail

any of these options is fine for me, can i do that?

Comment: Why not just add both your uni and gmail accounts to thunderbird?

Comment: @ekaj **thunderbird failed to find the settings for your account** i need to know the server hostname, pop3 or imap, which port. thunderbid failed to detect them automatically, otherwise i won't be asking this question, i tried configuring thunderbird but i coudn't do it

Comment: Ask your college.

Answer (score 0):

POP3 is normally on port 110 (try telnetting to: mail.university.com 110)

If you can't figure out the connection settings use the Outlook rules wizard to forward all mail to your gmail account, it's not that hard.